# matplotlib set_xdata plotting out of order

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipywidgets

I need to update a plot with `interact` and for that I use something like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[some data x],'y':[some data y]}
p, = ax.plot(df_temp.x,df_temp.y,'.-')
ax.set_xticks(x[::5])
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=45, fontsize=6)

@interact()
def update(i):
    df = pd.DataFrame(new data)
    p.set_xdata(df_temp.x)
    p.set_ydata(df_temp.y)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    ax.set_xticks(x[::5])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

which works fine when I have `datetime` type for `x`. But I changed it for string with `x = [datetime.strftime(y,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[:-3] for y in datetimedata]` because the plot had big gaps due to business days and times, which was not ideal. With the string x data, however, the gaps disappear but now, on some occasions, the plot is out of order, as can be seen here:

[data points 0,1 and 2 are out of order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex8if.png)

I know the data is still in the right order because I can print the dataframe and see the data is sorted. Also, when I create a new figure and axis and plot the data without the `interact` it shows in the right order too:

[x data in the right order plotted without `ax.set_xdata` and `interact`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n6PQ.png)

**EDIT**

The `x` column is already sorted, but the plot is out of order in the first picture. The first 3 rows are plotted on the right side of the chart.

```
                   x         y
0   2013-10-07 12:30 -0.008961
1   2013-10-07 13:30  0.003846
2   2013-10-07 14:30 -0.043890
3   2013-10-07 15:30  0.013083
4   2013-10-07 16:30  0.043967
..               ...       ...
85  2013-10-18 16:30 -0.036062
86  2013-10-18 17:30 -0.036062
87  2013-10-21 09:30 -0.015806
88  2013-10-21 10:30 -0.059842
89  2013-10-21 11:30 -0.132455
```

Comment: If you need to set the time format of the x-axis, the axis must be formatted after plotting, not as strings prior to plotting. If you must use strings, then you must always sort the columns. The first x values in the in the first plot, are not sorted.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear in the last paragraph. I edited the question to show the dataframe that generated the plot. The x column is sorted, but is plotted out of order.

Comment: The issue is not reproducible with the code and data provided.